# profiling function which has been optimized with optim

Tags: r, optimization, functional-programming

I have the following set of functions.

```
funk <- function(x,b) { 10^b * exp(-x/10) }

lambda <- function(y,k) { exp(-k*y) }

funk1 <- function(y,x,xb,b,k) { 
funk(x-xb-y,b) *exp(- integrate(lambda, lower=0, upper = y, k=k)$value) }

funk2 <-function(x,xb,b,k) { 
integrate(funk1, lower= 0, upper=x-xb, x=x,xb=xb, b=b,k=k)$value }

funk2_vc <- Vectorize(funk2)

optim_funk2 <- function(param) { 
b <-param[1]
k <- param[2]             
R1 <- sum((y - funk2_vc(xx,xb,b,k))^2)
-log(R1) } 

fit <- optim(par=c(5, 0.05), fn=optim_funk2)
```

and

```
xx <- seq(0,500,5)
xb <- seq(0,100,1)
y <- seq(1000,0,-10)
```

I wish to profile the function funk2 to figure out the path that `optim` has taken to estimate parameter values and if the function is optimizied for local or global minima.

I am a newbie to R and have no clue how to go about it. All suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple way to track the path of the parameters.  I'll use linear regression as an example.  Say our data is

```
x <- 1:10
y <- -3 + 2 * x + rnorm(length(x))
plot(x, y)
```

So `y` is a linear function of `x` plus some noise.  Our goal is to find parameters a and b such that the sum of squared errors `sum((y - (a + b * x))^2)` is minimized. (This can of course be solved algebraically, but for illustration we'll solve it with `optim()`.)

Here's the code to do the optimization and keep track of parameters:

```
par.path <- matrix(nrow=0, ncol=2, dimnames=list(NULL, c("a","b")))

funk <- function(par) {
  a <- par[1]; b <- par[2]
  par.path <<- rbind(par.path, par)
  sum((y - (a + b * x))^2)
}

optim(par=c(0,0), fn=funk)
```

The first line creates a 0-row matrix called `par.path` to store the parameter path.  Within the objective function `funk`, we add the current value of `par` to `par.path`.  Note that we have to use `<<-` rather than `<-` to update `par.path` because it lives outside the scope of `funk`.  (If we used `<-`, then `funk` would create a new local variable also called `par.path`, and the `par.path` outside the function wouldn't get updated.)  Since `optim` calls `funk` repeatedly, `par.path` will get progressively longer (more rows).

There are various ways to plot the matrix `par.path`.  Since in this case there are only two parameters, we can plot them against each other:

```
plot(par.path, type='l')
points(par.path[c(1,nrow(par.path)),], col=c("green","red"), cex=2, pch=16)
```

The 2nd line adds green and red dots to indicate the start and stop of the path.  More flexibly, we can plot all the columns of `par.path` against the iteration number of `optim`:

```
matplot(par.path, type='l', col=c("black","red"), lty=1)
legend("bottomleft", c("a","b"), col=c("black","red"), lty=1)
```

Here are these two plots. [image: paramter path plots]

Comment: Thanks for the answer and making it really comprehensible. I was looking for something else though but I found the answer using exactly same logic. Thanks a ton!